# Pointer name issue in Dynamic memory alloc

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int* InvBPSK(complex* Symbols, int ArraySize){

int *Bits = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*ArraySize);
if(!Bits){

    printf("Failed to allocate memory");
}
else{
for(int i=0; i<= ArraySize - 1;i++){
    if((double)creal(Symbols[i]) == -(1/sqrt(2)) && (double)cimag(Symbols[i]) == -(1/sqrt(2))){

        Bits[i] = 1;
    }
    else{
        Bits[i] = 0;


    }

}
}

return Bits;}
```

I was trying to allocate memory in my c code using malloc but something was going wrong when trying to use the allocated memory. Changing the name of the pointer solved this issue.

Comment: Any idea what could have been causing this?

Comment: "something was going wrong " is not a questions.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I am really not sure what was happening but if i try to run the code with the return variable name as BitStream the program crashes at the first use of that variable. When i changed the name to Bits, the program ran with no problems. I tried to use debug and add a break point at the end of the function with the name "BitStream" and the debug completed and returned the output correctly. That only caused more confusion for me.